# MVC: проблема с передачей значений текстовых полей

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Добрый день.

У меня в представлении 9 полей:

```
@model MatrixService.Models.SampleMatrix

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Ввод матрицы"; 
}

<h2>Ввод матрицы</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Заполните матрицу вручную</h4>
    <hr />

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.field11)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.field12)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.field13)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.field21)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.field22)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.field23)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.field31)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.field32)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.field33)
            </td>
        </tr> </table> </div> <p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Сгенерировать", "CreateMatrix") |
    @Html.ActionLink("Отмена", "Index")
```

После нажатия на кнопку сгенерировать, я вызываю действие `CreateMatrix`.

**Контроллер:**

```
    public ActionResult CreateMatrix(SampleMatrix m)
    {
        var t = 5;
        return RedirectToAction("UpdateMatrix");
    }
```

Но  в SampleMatrix m - все по нулям, хотя на форме я вводил значения.
**Что я не правильно сделал ?**
Спасибо

Comment: Добавьте модель в представление и с помощью модели делайте эдиторы и передавайте данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляем модель:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string CellOne { get; set; }
    public string CellTwo { get; set; }
    public string CellThree { get; set; }
    public string CellFour { get; set; }
    public string CellFive { get; set; }
    public string CellSix { get; set; }
    public string CellSeven { get; set; }
    public string CellEight { get; set; }
    public string CellNine { get; set; }
}
```

Добавляем в представление нашу модель:

```
@model /*пространство имен*/MyModel
```

Меняем наши эдиторы под модель:

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("CreateMatrix", null, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="item">
        <label>cell11</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CellOne)

        <label>cell12</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CellTwo)

        <label>cell13</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CellThree)
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <label>cell21</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CellFour)

        <label>cell22</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CellFive)

        <label>cell23</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CellSix)
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <label>cell31</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CellSeven)

        <label>cell32</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CellEight)

        <label>cell33</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CellNine)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Сгенерировать"/>
}
```

Ну и в контроллере методу `CreateMatrix` делаем параметр с типом `MyModel`, который теперь будет принимает модель.

После того, как Вы убрали `Html.BeginRouteForm` и `submit`-кнопку, а вместо них добавили `@Html.ActionLink` - данные с формы перестали отправляться с формы в контроллер, Вы просто создали ссылку. Для того, чтобы в контроллер пришли данные с формы, необходимо создать форму и отправить данные через `submit`, как было ранее.

Comment: Спасибо!
Имя параметра в котроллере имеет значение?

Comment: @LeonardBertone, ну, если только для `Ajax` когда через `JS` вызывать метод, то в `Url` нужно писать определенное имя, для обычных `BeginForm` вроде нет разницы

Comment: Я переписал свой код по Вашему образцу.
Посмотрите пожалуйста, у меня значения из полей все еще не передаются - в котролере все по нуля (

Comment: @LeonardBertone, так Вы же все поменяли...у Вас `ActionLink`, Вам нужно данные с формы отправить, значит нужна форма и сабмит, как было первоначально

Answer (score 1):

```
  public class ModelMatrix
  {
    public string Cell11 { get; set; }
    public string Cell12 { get; set; }
    public string Cell13 { get; set; }
    ...
  }

  public ActionResult CreateMatrix(ModelMatrix model)
  {
    ...
  }
```